# use :focus selector to change a label tag

Tags: css, css-selectors

so i want to change the label tag background color when the inputs is clicked. I also change the svg background color.

i have this image:
[image]

and i wanted to change it from grey to this orange when it gets clicked, this "cook" is defined in as a label

```css
.prep input[type=text]:focus{
  border-color: #D67200;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 #D67200;
}

.prep input[type=text]:focus + svg{
  background-color: #D67200;
}

.prep input[type=text]:focus + .label{
  background-color: #D67200;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container1">
                <input type="text" placeholder="something in">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 18 18">
                    <path d="M17.755,15.562l-3.505-3.5a.843.843,0,0,0-.6-.246h-.573a7.31,7.31,0,1,0-1.266,1.266v.573a.843.843,0,0,0,.246.6l3.505,3.5a.84.84,0,0,0,1.192,0l.995-.995a.848.848,0,0,0,0-1.2ZM7.313,11.811a4.5,4.5,0,1,1,4.5-4.5A4.5,4.5,0,0,1,7.313,11.811Z" />
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="container2">
                <input type="text" placeholder="something else">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 18 18">
                    <path d="M17.755,15.562l-3.505-3.5a.843.843,0,0,0-.6-.246h-.573a7.31,7.31,0,1,0-1.266,1.266v.573a.843.843,0,0,0,.246.6l3.505,3.5a.84.84,0,0,0,1.192,0l.995-.995a.848.848,0,0,0,0-1.2ZM7.313,11.811a4.5,4.5,0,1,1,4.5-4.5A4.5,4.5,0,0,1,7.313,11.811Z" />
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="prep">
                <input id="prep-input" type="text" placeholder="15 mins">
                <svg viewBox="0.6 0.56 18 18">
                    <path d="M9.562.563a9,9,0,1,0,9,9A9,9,0,0,0,9.562.563Zm2.072,12.705-3.2-2.326a.438.438,0,0,1-.178-.352V4.482a.437.437,0,0,1,.435-.435h1.742a.437.437,0,0,1,.435.435v5l2.3,1.677a.435.435,0,0,1,.094.61l-1.023,1.408A.438.438,0,0,1,11.635,13.268Z"/>
                </svg>
                <label class="label" for="prep-input">PREP</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the issue you're experiencing? Could you also post your HTML?

Comment: this just doesnt work on the label. is there a way to select both svg and the label together?

Comment: Screenshot of the unfocused and focused states? It's tough to know what "doesn't work" on the label without seeing it.